# Power BI slicer on project Tags where a project can have multiple tags

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling

I have the following 3 tables as shown on the attached image:

- aaa_Tags (List of all available Tags. Tag_ID is PRIMARY KEY)
- aaa_ProjectTagsBrdg (List of all Tag_ID, PR_ID pairs. A project can have 0 to many Tags.)
- aaa_Projects (List of all Projects & project details. PR_ID is PRIMARY KEY)

**Tables relationship:**

[image: tables relationship]

I am trying to create a slicer in PowerBI on Tags to show on a table only the Projects of the selected tag(s).
If no Tags are selected, show all Projects,
If e.g. Tag_ID = 3 is selected, show Projects with PR_ID (1,2,5)
If e.g. Tag_IDs (1 & 4) are selected, show Projects with PR_ID (1,5)

I will really appreciate if you can give me some guidance how to create a Power BI report doing the above.

Thanks

Comment: If you have set up relationships properly, when you select a specific tag, only the projects will be showing accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by changing the cross filter direction of the relationship between `aaa_Projects` and `aaa_projectTagsBrdg` to be `Both`:

[image]

Then your slicer will filter `aaa_projectTagsBrdg` and the filter will be propagated to `aaa_Projects` and you will get the filtering you want:

[image]

You can read more about cross filter direction here [Model relationships in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-relationships-understand#cross-filter-direction) and here [Enable bidirectional cross-filtering for DirectQuery in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-bidirectional-filtering).